# Virtual comparison operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there any reason to make the op== in a C++ base class non-virtual, i.e., is there any downside to this implementation:

```
class A {
  public:
  virtual bool operator== (const A& rhs) { ... }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
  bool operator== (const A& rhs) override { /* cast rhs to const B& */ {}
};
```

In my book they recommend to make the op== non-virtual and let it call a protected virtual member function which performs the polymorphism instead. It doesn't say anything about why they don't use the op== directly like I do in my example above. Is there a good reason I'm overlooking?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to support the [private virtual idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) where you separate out the base class public interface (which functions it exposes to calling code) from the internal implementation (how each function is actually written and how those responsibilities are distributed among implementer derived classes)

Comment: The same argument goes for the op= as well? But CLANG is even warning me that I'm using a virtual op=...what it is warning me of?